# error: Multiple commands produce (after eject react-native)

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, react-native-vector-icons

I wanted to change the application name so I changed it and deleted the iOS & android folders then I run `react-native eject` then I tried to build the project but I am facing 16 error from `vector-icon`

[image]

and I have the `UIAppFonts` in the iOS/projectName/Info.plist

```
<key>UIAppFonts</key>
<array>
    <string>AntDesign.ttf</string>
    <string>Entypo.ttf</string>
    <string>EvilIcons.ttf</string>
    <string>Feather.ttf</string>
    <string>FontAwesome.ttf</string>
    <string>FontAwesome5_Brands.ttf</string>
    <string>FontAwesome5_Regular.ttf</string>
    <string>FontAwesome5_Solid.ttf</string>
    <string>Fontisto.ttf</string>
    <string>Foundation.ttf</string>
    <string>Ionicons.ttf</string>
    <string>MaterialCommunityIcons.ttf</string>
    <string>MaterialIcons.ttf</string>
    <string>Octicons.ttf</string>
    <string>SimpleLineIcons.ttf</string>
    <string>Zocial.ttf</string>
</array>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Xcode, find the Copy Bundle Resources script in Build Phases tab, and see if the font files are listed there. If they are, removing them there should help.

Answer (score 0):

It took me a while (I'm a noob to XCode) to figure out Marek Lisik's answer so here is a picture of the steps he said.
[image]